# how to add interceptor in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0.3 for a project.My user info is loaded from the database. I have following interceptor

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
```

I want to add interceptor to user data. When I logging with user1(requester as role) he can see only specific user1 data.

```
http://localhost:7009/Test/requester//30351?menuId=app.requester.new
```

but when I logging with another user2(requester as role) and Enter above URL in browser.

```
http://localhost:7009/Test/requester//30351?menuId=app.requester.new.
```

he can see user1 data.

How can I add interceptor so that it restrict another user data.

Following is scenario
1> 
login with user1 and he can see following list of data 
101
102
103
when i clicks on 102 data it opens details of 102 data.

```
http://localhost:7009/Test/requester//102?menuId=app.requester.new.
```

2> login with user2 and he can see following list of data 
104
105
106

when i clicks on 105 data it opens details of 105 data.

```
http://localhost:7009/Test/requester//105?menuId=app.requester.new.
```

but when i copy user1 link

```
 http://localhost:7009/Test/requester//102?menuId=app.requester.new.
```

and paste into browser . user2 can see details of user1 data.

Comment: so either user1 or user2 can see user1's data? then why do you need to intercept the url since the data are public to all?

Comment: @gigadot: user1 can access user1 data and user2 can access user2 data. Following is the scenario.

Comment: @ gigadot: i have edited my question. how can restrict to user2 to access user1 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't filter everything in the spring security configuration but rather do it in view or controller. Here is a very good tutorial which shows you how to use spring security in your case.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

If you use JSP for your view, you can use spring security taglib to handle the view of user own data and, for other user's data, you will need to put the filtering logic inside the controller and pass them as model to the view. However, the exact solution depends on your application.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. yes I will need to modify fetching query. we can not do this using interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this is to use the Spring Expression Language and a custom Permission Evaluator.  Here's what we did to implement a department/sub-department authorization scheme [how to control the user authentication using spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928807/how-to-control-the-user-authentication-using-spring-mvc/7931657#7931657).  This will allow you to create custom logic to identify what user1 is allowed to see, etc.

Check out http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html.  Take a look at the @PostFilter annotation - if your data set is returned as a collection or an array Spring Security can automatically filter out data elements based on your custom Permission Evaluator.